# heroku deployment error when starting the server

Tags: node.js, heroku

hello i created an app based on a tutorial that works properly on my local. I use a sqlite in memory database (for development) and when i deploy i get the following error. Please tell me what details (i couldnt put the full log it was detected as spam) you need i am a newbie in node/hapi and heroku. THank you.

> 2020-03-27T13:21:21.337440+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/lib/models/index.js:7
>   2020-03-27T13:21:21.337489+00:00 app[web.1]: const dbSettings = Settings[Settings.env].db;
>   2020-03-27T13:21:21.337490+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
>   2020-03-27T13:21:21.337498+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   2020-03-27T13:21:21.337506+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: Cannot read property 'db' of undefined
>   2020-03-27T13:21:21.337507+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object. (/app/lib/models/index.js:7:43)
>   2020-03-27T13:21:21.337507+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
>   2020-03-27T13:21:21.337514+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
>   2020-03-27T13:21:21.337515+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
>   2020-03-27T13:21:21.337516+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
>   2020-03-27T13:21:21.337516+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1044:19)
>   2020-03-27T13:21:21.337516+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
>   2020-03-27T13:21:21.337516+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object. (/app/lib/controllers/home.js:3:16)
>   2020-03-27T13:21:21.337517+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
>   2020-03-27T13:21:21.337517+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
>   2020-03-27T13:21:21.337517+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
>   2020-03-27T13:21:21.337517+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
>   2020-03-27T13:21:21.337518+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1044:19)
>   2020-03-27T13:21:21.337518+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
>   2020-03-27T13:21:21.337518+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object. (/app/lib/routes.js:3:14)
>   2020-03-27T13:21:21.337518+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
>   2020-03-27T13:21:21.337519+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
>   2020-03-27T13:21:21.337519+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
>   2020-03-27T13:21:21.337519+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
>   2020-03-27T13:21:21.337519+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1044:19)
>   2020-03-27T13:21:21.337520+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
>   2020-03-27T13:21:21.337520+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object. (/app/server.js:7:16)
>   2020-03-27T13:21:25.387251+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=serene-scrubland-72461.herokuapp.com request_id=34632d56-e244-40de-b954-6854c2b08c7f fwd="86.250.193.144" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
>   2020-03-27T13:21:25.624603+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=serene-scrubland-72461.herokuapp.com request_id=123f2cd5-5644-4b53-97d3-183248ef8a7a fwd="86.250.193.144" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

Answer (score 0):

solved by using postgres addons from heroku